# How to give categories open/closed status?

Tags: ee2, categories, status, gwcode-categories, child-categories

Long story short, I have a situation where categories are treated like channel entries as far as generating lists of content on the front-end (using gwcode_categories inside channel entries.) I have a user who would like to turn some of the categories off the way she's done with channels, setting statuses to Closed.

Is there a way I can give categories open/closed statuses without having to resort to custom SQL/PHP? I would be willing to pay for a premium plugin to add this feature.

This is on EE 2.8.1.

Answer (score 3):

Custom category field?

[image]

Which defaults to open:

[image]

Then your template code:

```
{exp:gwcode_categories channel="example" depth="1" custom_fields="yes" linear="yes"}
    {if cat_status == "Open"}{cat_name}{/if}
{/exp:gwcode_categories}
```

Note the additional parameter `custom_fields="yes"`.

Comment: Thanks, Peter. Good thought. I was stuck making this work for a bit until I realized linear=yes would stop gwcode_categories from outputting default <li> tags, letting me nest them inside the if conditional.